# How to get multi columns via subquery?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to get members and their photos. Every member has 2 photos. (I am not talking about profile image)

There are 2 tables named as Members and MemberPhotos.

Here is my query which doesn't work(expectedly):

```
SELECT
M.Name as MemberName,
M.LastName as MemberLastName,

(
    SELECT
        TOP 1
        MP.PhotoName
    FROM
        MemberPhotos MP
    WHERE
        MP.MemberID = M.ID
        AND
        MP.IsFirst = 1
) as MemberFirstPhoto,

(
    SELECT
        TOP 1
        MP.PhotoName
    FROM
        MemberPhotos MP
    WHERE
        MP.MemberID = M.ID
        AND
        MP.IsFirst = 0
) as MemberSecondPhoto,

FROM
    Members M
```

Maybe somebody going to say that I should use inner join instead, I don't want to use inner join, if I use it I get data multiple like:

```
Name       Surname       PhotoName

Bill       Gates         bill.png
Bill       Gates         bill2.png
Steve      Jobs          steve.jpg
Steve      Jobs          steve2.jpg
```

What do you recommend me about query?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** 
Here is the output I want to get:

```
Name       Surname       FirstPhoto       SecondPhoto

Bill       Gates         bill.png         bill2.png
Steve      Jobs          steve.jpg        steve2.png
```

Answer (score 1):

The only issue with your example query is that you have an extra comma after

```
as MemberSecondPhoto
```

If you remove this it works fine.

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85f1b/2).

However, while that query is working now, because you know that each member only has two photos, you can use a much simpler query:

```
SELECT
  M.Name as MemberName,
  M.LastName as MemberLastName,
  MPF.PhotoName as MemberFirstPhoto,
  MPS.PhotoName as MemberSecondPhoto
FROM Members M
  LEFT JOIN MemberPhotos MPF ON M.ID = MPF.MemberID AND MPF.IsFirst = 1
  LEFT JOIN MemberPhotos MPS ON M.ID = MPS.MemberID AND MPS.IsFirst = 0
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85f1b/4).